# Google Custom Search Site Restricted JSON API more than 10 sites

Tags: google-search, google-custom-search, google-search-api, google-search-console

I am wanting to use a Google Custom Search to search only 60 specific sites. Looking at Custom Search Site Restricted JSON API there is a limit to only 10 sites. Is there a way to search more than 10 sites?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the non-site restricted flavor of the API.
If you need more than 10K QPD quota, you can apply for an exception via the cloud console.

Comment: I am still not seeing how I can search 60 specific sites using the non-site restricted API either, there seems to be many restrictions in that api as well. The documentation available does not really show this.

Comment: Step one is to create a Custom Search Engine that searches the 60 sites you want: https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4513886
Then you can use that CSE with the Custom Search JSON API by passing the appropriate 'cx' parameter

Answer (score 1):

Site Restricted can allow only [10 sites](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/site_restricted_api#about_the). I haven't carried out but there could be 2 solutions:

- Build and aggregate results from `60/10=6` search engines
- Using non-restricted and build the query for whitelists only with `site:` and boolean operator `OR` (or `|`). Eg: `q=site:stackoverflow.com|quora.com search engine`